# How can i move to next object in recyclerview on button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to move to next object in recyclerview when button is clicked. I tried using scrollToPosition but i can't figure out how can i get current position of the object. If i put a number in there then it works, but then it only jumps to that position only.

Code i am using to scroll

```
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(2);
```

Answer (score 14):

[LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()) - methods like `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` and checking the size of your AdapterItems and scrolling to the next (+1 if findLast < adapter.itemsSize). Very simple logic.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Logic for button clicking:

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < (adapter.getItemCount() - 1)) {
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
        }

    }
});
```

And in your extended Adapter for RecyclerView, you should have something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return yourData != null ? yourData.length() : 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks simple, but i am still learning android. Can you show how to put it in code?

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewHolder` has a `getAdapterPosition` function returning its position